# Regex got Splitting comma seperated String ignoring commas in double quotes

Tags: regex

I have a string like this

```
4458820,9/7/2012,91723,6,6C    ,1422,TSTOP ,TRAFFIC STOP  ','  1 ',' 2
```

I need to split this string at each commas and should skip the commas enclosed in single quotes.

Expected Result:

```
4458820
9/7/2012
91723
6
6C    
1422
TSTOP 
TRAFFIC STOP  ','  1 ',' 2
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this through Regex.

This is what i am trying now..

`String[] tokens = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=([^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)");`

Comment: If you want this much logic in it, you probably want to just write some custom code for it. What language are you using? Java?

Comment: The language/tool is **essential** for regex questions. What are you using?

Comment: This string looks really strange. Wouldn't *4458820,9/7/2012,91723,6,6C    ,1422,TSTOP ,'TRAFFIC STOP, 1, 2'* make more sense ?

Comment: Why would commas be in quotes and not the field data ? Are you trying to fix a damaged csv text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on comma with lookarounds surrounding it:

```
(?<!'),(?!')
```

i.e.:

```
String[] tokens = Regex.Split(line, @"(?<!'),(?!')");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sV4cQ1/1)